# Way to find matching (closing) JavaScript bracket in Chrome Devtools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

JavaScript newbie here. I'm reviewing a big swath of JS code using devtools and I'm wondering if there's an easy way to locate where the closing bracket is on a function. Is there a feature where I can highlight an opening bracket and pinpoint where the closing bracket is located?

Comment: The "sources" tab has syntax highlighting.

Comment: hi ben, if you are still active, it would be nice to accept one of these answers

Answer (score 23):

You can use a chrome devtool shortcut. First move the cursor next to opening or closing bracket then do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd>. Note this also works for parenthesis and curly brackets.

To see all the available shortcuts click on three dots icon at the top right side of devtools then click on `Shortcuts`.

Comment: @AamirKhan, probably OP dont know about accepting an answer after asking something. though it is an old topic, lets warn him to do that.

Comment: It's worth noting that **the cursor won't jump if a matching bracket isn't found**. You'll also be able to tell that the bracket is mismatched by an orange-red highlight and underline of that character when your cursor is next to it. For matching brackets, the highlight is gray.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the sources tab. 
It has few buttons in the footbar, which has pretty print which looks like this:
`{}` which displays the formatted JS. When you put your cursor on a brace the other (closing or opening ) brace is automatically matched for you.

For latest devtools in chrome, use chrome canary.

refer > https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: This feature is enabled in latest release Chrome (28).

Comment: Yes, chrome has auto updates enabled for me, and i was using this feature for some time now.. There are other options like plugins `webdeveloper` and `firebug` for chrome which also help.

Comment: +1. To further elaborate, both opening and closing braces will be **underlined** (i.e. they will have an **underscore beneath** them). At least this is how it is in the latest version as of now - Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Answer (score -2):

As far as I am aware their is no way within the chrome dev tools but if you copy and paste the code into a program such as Notepad ++ or Dreamweaver and put your cursor to the right of one of the brackets then the corresponding bracket will be highlighted.

Comment: See the answer above.